# Bot not creating channel - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Whenever I attempt to use my bot to create a channel, it does not create the channel.

```
let name = 'DING'
message.guild.createChannel(name, 'text')
```

It sends the error "type: Value "text" is not int." With this, I assume text must become an integer, however this code worked in the past, and created a text channel with that name. Even the documentation shows the exact thing that I am doing. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs at [discord.js.org](https://discord.js.org), you can see that the documentation for the [create channel method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createChannel) isn't what you think it is.

What i think you will want is:

```
let name = 'DING'
message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: 'text' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Don't forget to do `.catch()` so that you know if the promise is rejected and an error occures.

Comment: This gives me a similar error:
`type: Value "{u'type': u'text'}" is not int.`

Comment: Strange... Could you share some more of your code? I have a feeling that something else is going awry with your code

Comment: Here's my github repository - the needed info is in the bot.js - I'll share some code here but if it doesn't seem like enough information you're free to take a look:
https://github.com/madisonb0074/ARGBot

I believe this is the necessary information: 
`client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('however')) {
    let name = 'Conditioned'
    let guild = message.guild
    guild.createChannel(name, { type: 'text' })
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error)
  }
}`

I think this may be a problem with the Discord.js version.

Comment: Sounds likely, i cannot seem to see any issues with that code block.